# UNIX spawn sandboxed process

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, operating-system

In my scenario, the parent process generates some machine code (dynamically), this code should then be executed by the child process. The child process should not be able to access the parents resources (so no forking), for security reasons, it has to be as restricted as possible, I want something like that:

```
process_handle x;
give_memory_page_to_process(x, mempage); // allows x to access the page
/*some more pages for the child*/
/*remove the memory pages from the parent process*/
execute(x); // should create a process with just the given pages
```

Comment: no forking? How else do you create a child process?

Comment: If you need to ensure that the child code has no access to any data from the parent, the simplest way by far would be to `exec()` some trivial helper program whose only job is to load and run the code.  You also have to close fds and so forth. On the other hand, if you don't trust the child code with read-only access to the parent's memory, are you sure you trust it to execute at all (with full ability to make system calls, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup an *empty vessel*, you will need to fork() then have the child exec() into an *empty* process which you will then write into.
The easiest way is probably to have the parent generate its machine code into an ELF (or other) format file, and have the child close fds, etc... then exec it.

Since the initial child (after fork) is identical to the parent, there is no security issue yet.   The child is then going to shut down all its fds, possibly chroot()ing to somewhere restrictive, that the parent has placed the generated code into.  The child then exec()s that generated code.

If you are worried somebody can attack the executable inside your chrooted directory, why aren't you worried that they can attack the parent?  Same permissions....